# Why does my MVC foreach loop fail to work?

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

I'm actually learning how to hydrate an object in php with MVC design pattern and mysql DB. However, I'm facing a problem. My foreach loop doesn't work in my view. More precisely, we cannot even enter into the loop to display my data.

Here is my code.

index.php : the root of my project

```
<?php


require ("./Configuration/Configuration.php");
require('Controller/Controller.php');

try {
    if (isset($_GET['action'])) {
        if ($_GET['action'] == 'listPosts') {
            listPosts();
        }
        elseif ($_GET['action'] == 'post') {
            if (isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] > 0) {
                post();
            }
            else {
                throw new Exception('Erreur : aucun identifiant de billet envoyé');
            }
        }
        elseif ($_GET['action'] == 'addComment') {
            if (isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] > 0) {
                if (!empty($_POST['author']) && !empty($_POST['comment'])) {
                    addComment($_GET['id'], $_POST['author'], $_POST['comment']);
                }
                else {
                    throw new Exception('Erreur : tous les champs ne sont pas remplis !');
                }
            }
            else {
                throw new Exception('Erreur : aucun identifiant de billet envoyé');
            }
        }
        elseif ($_GET['action'] == 'modifyComment'){
            if (isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id']>0) {
                getCommentary();
            }
        }

        elseif ($_GET['action'] == "setComment") {
            modifyCommentary($_POST['comment'], $_GET['id'], $_GET['post_id']);
        }
    }
    else {
        listPosts();
    }
}

catch (Exception $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
}
```

Controller.php : my main controller

```
<?php
require("./Model/PostManager.php");


function listPosts() {
    $postManager = new PostManager();
    $posts = $postManager->getPosts();
    require ("./View/listPostsView.php");
}
```

Manager.php : my model where I declare and set the connection to my DB. It's also in this file where I defined my operations such as projection (select * ) and projection with a condition (select my_data from my_table where my_condition).

```
<?php


    class Manager
    {
        private $db = null;
        private static $instance = null;
    
        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->db =  new PDO('mysql:host='. HOST . ';dbname='. DB_NAME . ';charset='.CHARSET, ID_USER, PASSWORD, array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
        }
    
        protected function getDb() {
            return $this->db;
        }
    
        public static function getInstance() {
            if (is_null(self::$instance)) {
                self::$instance = new Manager();
            }
            return self::$instance;
        }
    
        
        public function request($sql, $args) {
    
            if ($args == null) {
                $req = Manager::getInstance()->getDb()->query($sql);
            }
    
            else {
                $req = Manager::getInstance()->getDb()->prepare($sql);
                $req->execute(array($args));
            }
    
            return $req;
        }
    
        
        public function queryBy($sql, $args = null) {
            try {
                $pdo = $this->request($sql, $args);
                $req = $pdo->fetch();
                $pdo->closeCursor();
            }
            catch (PDOExecption $e) {
                die("Erreur : " . $e->getMessage());
            }
            return $req;
    
        }
    
        
        public function queryAll($sql, $args = null) {
            try {
                $pdo = $this->request($sql, $args);
                $req = $pdo->fetch();
                $pdo->closeCursor();
            }
    
            catch (PDOExecption $e) {
                die("Erreur : " . $e->getMessage());
            }
    
            return $req;
    
        }
    
        
        public function hydrate(array $data) {
            foreach ($data as $key => $val) {
                $method = "set".ucfirst($key);
                    if(method_exists($this, $method)) {
                        $this->$method($val);
                    }
            }
    
            return $this;
        }
    
    
    }
```

Post : the object which I want to hydrate

```
<?php

class Post extends Manager
{
    private $_id;
    private $_title;
    private $_content;
    private $_creation_date;

    /**
     * Post constructor.
     * @param $data
     */
    public function __construct($data = array())
    {
        $this->hydrate($data);
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->_id;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $id
     */
    public function setId($id): void
    {
        $this->_id = $id;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getTitle()
    {
        return $this->_title;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $title
     */
    public function setTitle($title): void
    {
        $this->_title = $title;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getContent()
    {
        return $this->_content;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $content
     */
    public function setContent($content): void
    {
        $this->_content = $content;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getCreationDate()
    {
        return $this->_creation_date;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $creation_date
     */
    public function setCreationDate($creation_date): void
    {
        $this->_creation_date = $creation_date;
    }






}
```

PostManager : The file where I can execute operations to my hydrated object

```
<?php

require_once ("Manager.php");
require_once ("./Entities/Post.php");


class PostManager
{
 
    public function getPosts()
    {
        $manager = new Manager();
        $sql = 'SELECT id, title, content, DATE_FORMAT(creation_date, \'%d/%m/%Y à %Hh%imin%ss\') AS creation_date_fr FROM posts ORDER BY creation_date DESC LIMIT 0, 5';
        $req = $manager->queryAll($sql);
        $post = new Post($req);

        return $post;
    }
    
    public function getPost($postId)
    {

        $sql ='SELECT id, title, content, DATE_FORMAT(creation_date, \'%d/%m/%Y à %Hh%imin%ss\') AS creation_date_fr FROM posts WHERE id = ?';
        $req = $this->queryBy(sql,$postId);

        return $req;
    }

}
```

ListPostView : my view where I want to display my data but I can't beacause I cannot enter in my foreach loop

```
<?php $title = 'Mon blog'; ?>

<?php ob_start(); ?>
    <h1>Mon super blog !</h1>
    <p>Derniers billets du blog :</p>


<?php
var_dump($posts); // This variable is displayed on the browser but after this, we cannot display anything
foreach ($posts as $post): // Foreach loop which doesn't work
    echo "toto"; // I cannot enter into this foreach to display a simple string
    ?>
    <div class="news">
        <h3>
            <?= htmlspecialchars($post->getTitle()) ?>
            <em>le <?= $post->getCreationDate() ?></em>
        </h3>

        <p>
            <?= nl2br(htmlspecialchars($post->getContent())) ?>
            <br/>
            <em><a href="./index.php?action=post&id=<?= $post->getId() ?>">Commentaires</a></em>
        </p>
    </div>
    <?php
endforeach;
?>
<?php $content = ob_get_clean(); ?>

<?php require('template.php'); ?>
```

Could you help me to solve this problem please ?

Regards

YT

---

## Edit 1

This is the output from the server:

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BH5AS.png

Comment: What does `var_dump($posts);` output? Have you checked the servers error log for errors? Have you checked what the generated HTML looks like? You need to debug the issue to narrow down where it goes wrong. Now you've just posted a bunch of code (where most of it most likely is irrelevant to the issue), basically asking us to read through it all and guess what anything contains.

Comment: could it have something to do with the fact that you're using `ob_start()` and `ob_get_clean()`...? Try `echo $content;`

Comment: Your method `getPosts()` fetches multiple posts, but then you pass the result of the SQL query to `new Post()`, which is for a single post? It should most likely be an array of `Post`-instances.

Comment: Actually, `queryAll()` uses `fetch()` which only returns one single row. So... your `queryAll()` only returns one single post. Then you pass that Post object to your view as  
`$posts`, which you try and iterate over. Please do some debugging and check that your methods actually returns what you expect.

Comment: I have the put a screen shot of the output in my previous post